# Why node js is not creating new file again after deleting it

Tags: node.js

I wrote a Node js program with the following steps -

- Check if file ~/temp.txt exists
- If not create new file
- Write some content into the file

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {

  const homedir = os.homedir();

  if (fs.existsSync(`${homedir}/temp.txt`)) {
  } else {
    fs.writeFile(`${homedir}/temp.txt`, '', { flag: 'wx' }, function (err) {});
  }

  // writing some content to the file
  // ...

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
}
```

When I am running `curl localhost:3000` -

- First, it did not find any file. So it created new file and write content as expected
- Now I deleted the file manually and hit the `curl` command again
- Now it identified file does not exist, but not creating new one.

I am unable to understand why it is creating the file successfully for the first time and not creating after deleting it manually.

Comment: Do you know for sure that it called `fs.writeFile()` second time, without error? Your error handling is a no-op.

Comment: Clue #1.  When something isn't working properly, don't be using `function (err) {}` for your error handling.  Instead, LOG ALL POSSIBLE ERRORS.  And, make sure you are logging all possible paths through your code (or stepping through it in the debugger) so you know exactly which path through your code it is taking.